# How does R know what kind of data from a given data-frame to consider as a factor?

Tags: r

Considering the given data from the Titanic dataset available on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data), I am trying to find out what the data type of each of the column is on R. It return a factor datatype for Name of passengers,gender and ticket number. It returns a number datatype for age. Why doesn't it consider the list of ages to be an integer or even a factor? The ages do repeat themselves in the data set. Can't they considered as different levels?

I used the `str()` function to return the datatypes in R.

```
str(test.survived)
 $ Age        : num  34.5 47 62 27 22 14 30 26 18 21 ...
 $ Ticket     : Factor w/ 363 levels "110469","110489",..: 153 222 74 148 139 262 159 85 101 270 ...
```

.

```
str(test.survived)
```

Output:

```
    'data.frame':   418 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ survived   : Factor w/ 1 level "None": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PassengerId: int  892 893 894 895 896 897 898 899 900 901 ...
 $ Pclass     : int  3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 ...
 $ Name       : Factor w/ 418 levels "Abbott, Master. Eugene Joseph",..: 210  
                409 273 414 182 370 85 58 5 104 ...
 $ Sex        : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ Age        : num  34.5 47 62 27 22 14 30 26 18 21 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Ticket     : Factor w/ 363 levels "110469","110489",..: 153 222 74 148 139 
                262 159 85 101 270 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.83 7 9.69 8.66 12.29 ...
 $ Cabin      : Factor w/ 77 levels "","A11","A18",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                 ...
 $ Embarked   : Factor w/ 3 levels "C","Q","S": 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 1 3 ...
```

From what I understand, factors are used for datasets that have duplicate values, hence categorizing them into levels. Just like the ticket number, and the cabin type, age also has duplicates. But R doesn't consider age to be a factor and assigns it a number datatype. I understand it can't be an integer type since there are some floating data values in there. But why not factor?

Comment: Unless you set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE`, `R` will almost always treat them as factors during data import. Could you share what code you used to read the data?

Comment: It doesn't convert tickets into numeric because there are tickets like: `A./5. 2152` which contain letters. If it was only numbers it would convert it to numeric like age.

Comment: "factors are used for datasets that have duplicate values" -- no, they are for data that have at most a categorical interpretation. Alternatives: ordinal, cardinal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable

Comment: additionally, to convert to factor variables with a small number of distinct values , using *tidyverse* `mutate_if(your_df, ~n_distinct(.) <= 10, factor)`

Answer (score 6):

What the data is read as will depend on the function you use to do so as well as any arguments you specify.

If you used something like `read.csv()`, then that uses the function `type.convert()` to set the data type for each column. From the [notes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/utils/html/type.convert.html):

> Given a vector, the function attempts to convert it to logical, integer, numeric or complex, and failing that converts a character vector to factor unless as.is = TRUE. The first type that can accept all the non-missing values is chosen.

The function goes through class types in that order to work out what the column should be. So a factor type will only be used if a numeric category can't be assigned. In this instance it is a numeric column.

**More info**

Often, people don't want their character columns read in as factors. To avoid this, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading in the csv.

If you want your numeric column to be factors, then you can use

```
test.survived$Age <- as.factor(test.survived$Age)
```

for example.

Comment: Great response. I would add that because of this R will convert anything that can be numeric to a number and will drop leading zeroes. So it may be necessary to define columns manually when importing things like ticket numbers or id numbers.

Comment: May be worth noting that you can also just tell R what classes you want the columns to be when reading the data, using the the `colClasses` argument in `read.table`, and thus in `read.csv`.